# Rsyslog logs readable by all users

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux, syslog

I have an rsyslog instance in a RHEL8 linux server that is used to collect logs from other systems. That works fine, and it stores all the logs in the `/var/log` directory with following format `/var/log/hostname/year/month/date`.

My problem is my username does not have read rights right away, so first I have to `sudo chmod o+r` in order to be able to read the logs or use root account, which I do not want to do.

I have tried solving this in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file by adding

```
$FileCreateMode 0022
$umask 0022
```

which should give read permissions to all users, but it didn't work.

I have also modified the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service` file with `UMask=0022`, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command tells `rsyslog` to create the file with only write permissions for group and other:

```
$FileCreateMode 0022
```

Demonstration:

```
touch x
chmod 0022 x
ls -l x
-----w--w-+ 1 roaima roaima 0 Mar 28 09:28 x
```

This command tells `rsyslog` to mask off the group and other write permissions

```
$umask 0022
```

The mask is a set of bits that *should not* be set, so it's inverted with respect to the normal permissions settings. What you wrote here is "deny everything *except* group and other write permission". The net effect is no permission for anyone.

What you probably want is shown in the [`rsyslog` documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/action/rsconf1_filecreatemode.html)

```
$umask 0000             # Don't let the umask get in the way
$FileCreateMode 0644    # u=rw,g=r,o=r
$DirCreateMode 0755     # u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
```

Comment: I tried setting those permissions as you mentioned and restarted the service, but whenever I try to `cd` into the directory for the new day, it says I have no permission. These are the permissions I get drwx------, so no permissions for other users. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Hamperfait https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/action/rsconf1_dircreatemode.html your question didn't mention anything about directory permissions so I didn't address those

Comment: I also tried adding the `$DirCreateMode 0644` and restarted the rsyslog service, but newly created directories are `drwx------` and newly created files have `-rw-r-----` permissions, so still no read permission for others.

Comment: @Hamperfait it would have to be `0755` for a directory; I've added this to the answer